# Extracting subrows from rows

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataset having year, total runs scored per ball, inning and batting_team.
i want to display the data where i will have year in which innings are displayed in which i will list the team who has scored the highest runs in that inning of that year

i have reached till this extent but dont know to take the max out of the years(row-wise) and total(column-wise)

```
a = pd.DataFrame((df.groupby(['year','inning','batting_team'])["total"].sum()))
```

[This is the result of the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JleOb.png)

i want only the team who has scored the highest among other teams to be displayed of that year's inning
For example :-
2008 1 DeccanChargers  somevalue(max runs scored in that years 1st inning)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the top result for each GroupBy you can use `.head(1)`

Comment: i dont want the top result ...i want the maximum scored in that year's inning

Comment: column 'total' is the total of all the runs scored by teams in that year's inning(1 or 2)

Comment: Please explain what you would like to see instead of what you're seeing now. Thanks.

Comment: The image I have uploaded have the collection of teams and their runs according to year's innings

I only want to display the team with the maximum runs scored in that year and in that inning

Comment: Sorry, are you hoping that your final result will be:  **2008 1 Chennai Super Kings 1548** on the first line and then **2008 2 Chennai Super Kings 972**?

Comment: Only the first statement that you mentioned

Comment: As it is the maximum in that group...so for every year the team's name who scored maximum number of runs in that year's innings

Comment: I think it would be very easy to help you if you showed us a small sample of your original data. If I am understanding you correctly, you have the individual games, you total them for the whole year (by year/team/inning) and then you're looking to see how to aggregate by **just** year for the maximum value, right?